# Traceback: KeyError: 'twitter' python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, configparser

I am having an issue when running my code. I am trying to connect to the Twitter API and retrieve the keys from a dictionary that is in a config.ini file. The Traceback that I get is:

```
  File "c:\Users\Dino\Projects\TwitterNLP\twitter_api.py", line 20, in <module>
    api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
  File "C:\Users\Dino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'twitter'
```

```
import tweepy
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']
access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print(api.me().name)
```

My config file:

```
[twitter]

api_key =
api_key_secret =

access_token =
access_token_secret =
```

So my question is, why is this traceback occuring and how do I fix it?

Comment: probably because your config does not have section `twitter`!?

Comment: My config file:

[twitter]

api_key =
api_key_secret =

access_token =
access_token_secret =

Comment: @dinosaurslayer, please [edit] that into your question as a code block.

Comment: Try an absolute path to the INI file. A relative path may not point to where you think it does.

Comment: `ConfigParser.read()` [returns an empty list](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) (instead of raising an exception, for example) if it cannot find the file: "If none of the named files exist, the `ConfigParser` instance will contain an empty dataset.  An application which requires initial values to be loaded from a file should load the required file or files using [`read_file()`](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) before calling `read()` for any optional files".

Comment: Thank you Chris, config.read_file(open('config.ini')) seems to work.